# Как найти прямоугольники на изображении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Есть такой скрипт

```
import cv2
import numpy
from PIL import Image
"""
# параметры цветового фильтра
hsv_min = numpy.array((0, 70, 150), numpy.uint16)
hsv_max = numpy.array((255, 255, 255), numpy.uint16)
"""

# параметры цветового фильтра
hsv_min = numpy.array((0, 70, 150), numpy.uint8)
hsv_max = numpy.array((255, 255, 255), numpy.uint8)


class ImageCandlesProcessing(object):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        pil_image = image
        numpy_array = numpy.array(pil_image)
        # convert to a openCV2 image, notice the COLOR_RGB2BGR which means tha
        # the color is converted from RGB to BGR format
        self.opencv_image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        self.boxes = []
    def preparation(self):
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.opencv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # меняем цветовую модель с BGR на HSV
        self.thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max) # применяем цветовой фильтр
    def find_contours(self):
        # ищем контуры и складируем их в переменную contours
        (contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(self.thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for contour in contours:
            cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            rectangle = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rectangle)
            box = numpy.int0(box)
            self.boxes.append(box)
    def draw_contours(self):
        for box in self.boxes:
            cv2.drawContours(self.opencv_image, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    def converting_opencv_to_pil_image(self):
        self.image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(self.opencv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    def show_image(self):
        cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Image', 300, 400)
        cv2.imshow('Image', self.opencv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
"""
image = Image.open("input.png")

image_processing = ImageCandlesProcessing(image)
image_processing.preparation()
image_processing.find_contours()
image_processing.draw_contours()
image_processing.show_image()
"""
```

[image: Изображение]

Вроде справляется с поиском но иногда не совсем

[image: Изображение 2]

Вопроса два как оптимизировать код что бы выделялись контуры без учёта теней

И как вырезать эти контуры для дальнейшего анализа то есть цвет и высота

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По вопросу теней я не понял. Однако это может быть связано с непониманием hsv формата.

```
# параметры цветового фильтра
hsv_min = numpy.array((0, 70, 150), numpy.uint8)
hsv_max = numpy.array((255, 255, 255), numpy.uint8)
```

Как я вижу, цвета инициализированы наугад и удачу.

[Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv)

---

Задача определения цвета каждой свечи, по моему, слишком странная. Применить цветовой фильтр дважды и получить две маски свечей по цвету более рационально.

---

Высоту контура можно получить с помощью cv2.boundingRect(contour). Реализован в Candle.render (см ниже).

---

Ниже моя реализация нахождения свечей и используемое при ней изображение.

```
# Дата: July 26th, 2020.
import cv2
import numpy

class Candle:
    """
    Контейнер для свечи.
    """
    # Типы свечей.
    up = "<ядовитая свеча>"
    down = "<падать вниз молодцом свеча>"

    def __init__(self, type, contour):

        self.type = type
        self.contour = contour

    def render(self, canvas):
        
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(self.contour)
        color = (2, 235, 25) if self.type == Candle.up else (25, 2, 233)
        cv2.rectangle(canvas, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, -1)

COLOR_FILTER = \
{   Candle.up: (
        numpy.array([60, 100, 30], numpy.uint8),
        numpy.array([90, 180, 180], numpy.uint8)),
    Candle.down: (
        numpy.array((150, 110, 40), numpy.uint8),
        numpy.array((170, 170, 170), numpy.uint8)),
}

def Candles(image, debug = False):
    # Возвращает список найденных свеч на изображении объектами Candle.

    def Extract(type, mask):
        # Возвращает список найденных свеч на изображении в местах маски объектами Candle.
        scr = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(scr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        (contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        result = list()
        for contour in contours:
            result.append(Candle(type, contour))

        return result

    # Применим цветной фильтр к каждому типу свечи.
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    up = cv2.inRange(hsv, *COLOR_FILTER[Candle.up])
    down = cv2.inRange(hsv, *COLOR_FILTER[Candle.down])

    # К просмотру предварительного результата.
    if debug:
        cv2.imshow("up", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = up))
        cv2.imshow("down", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = down))
        cv2.imshow("common", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = up + down))
        cv2.imshow("other", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = 255 - (up + down)))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    result = list()
    result += Extract(Candle.up, up)
    result += Extract(Candle.down, down)

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file = "7081e63154fd4d56a0c2a00ae5ee116a.py.png"
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    candles = Candles(image, True)

    # Нарисуем найденные свечи сandles.
    canvas = numpy.zeros(image.shape, numpy.uint8)
    for candle in candles:
        candle.render(canvas)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imshow("Out", canvas)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: source.png]

В итоге рисуется холст, который отображает то же самое положение свечей и их тип (по цвету), что и исходное.

Comment: А вы не могли бы на примере моего первого рисунка показать что там подряд идут 4 красных  свечи и последняя зелёная) Как это реализовать?

Comment: И да я понятия не имею что такое цветовой фильтр и как с ним работать

Comment: То есть вы пишите комментарий «параметры цветового фильтра» и понятия не имеете что делаете? Тут мои полномочия оканчиваются. [Базовые методы обработки изображений.](http://mechanoid.kiev.ua/cv-image-detector.html). По сути это cv2.inRange. Ключевая фраза «понятия не имею» означает, что пора бы и иметь, раз пытаетесь плавать в этом.

Comment: Логика такая на снимке всегда пять свечей мне надо знать что 4 из них уже красные и какого размера и последняя зелёная ваш ответ конечно интересен и грамотен но я всё равно не понимаю как добиться желаемого результата

Comment: Если честно результат моего скрипта это копипаста из разных источников)

Comment: Достаточно разобраться с первой ссылкой ответа, изменить hsv цвета COLOR_FILTER под ваши  цвета свечей и имя файла file с изображением.

Comment: Можно еще с помощью морфологии выделять отдельно  также и "фитиль" свечи.